# How do I assign Shift-Delete to do exactly same as Fn-Delete on Mac Keyboard using OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like for RightShift-Delete to perform exactly as Fn-Delete currently behaves (deletes character right of cursor) on my Mac using OS X 10.9.5.

I don't want to use another app. I'm hoping there's a way to directly map or bind those keys within the OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) though I've not used it extensively myself.

I'm not certain if it's possible to distinguish between right & left shift, though.

Comment: Thanks, I don't expect there will be a distinction either, but wanted to be most precise.  As for my lack of precision, I should have also said I don't really want to use another app.  Was hoping there's a way to directly map or bind those keys within the OS itself.

Comment: not as far as I know - Karabiner is the go-to app for this kind of thing